# Finding the number of ordering n with *badness* $k$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

In a class there are $n$ students with unequal heights.

(i) Find the number of orderings of the students such that the shortest person is not at the front and the tallest person is not at the end.

(ii) For $1≤i≤n$, let $b_i$ denote the number of students in front of the $i_{th}$ student who are taller than the $i_{th}$ student. For example, consider the sequence $[4,1,2,6,7,5]$, with 4 being the front 5 being the end. Then,
$$b_1=0,b_2=1,b_3=1,b_4=0,b_5=0,b_6=2$$
Define the *$badness$* of an ordering as $\max_{i∈[n]}b_i$. The example sequence has $badness$ of $2$. Let $f_k(n)$ denote the number of orderings of $[n]$ that have $badness$ $k$. Find $f_k(n)$.

This is problem **B4** from the **CMI** (Chennai Mathematical Institute) Undergraduate exam that was held this year.
I could obviously solve the first part, but in the second part I am having difficultly in finding a way to group the cases together so as to find a formula. It would be useful if anyone can provide a hint or a way for counting the different cases for solving this question. Thank you!

Comment: polynomial and $f(f(x))=f(x)$ one as well

Comment: It is easier to count the sequences with "badness" $< k$

Comment: @BrianMoehring, yes, that is actually a hint that was provided in the exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g_k(n)$ denote the number of sequences of length $n$ with "badness" $< k$.

In order to have a sequence with "badness" $<k$, the last student must be one of the $k$ tallest students, and in front of them must be a sequence of $n-1$ students with badness $< k$.  Specifically, this means
$$g_k(n) = \min(k,n) \cdot g_k(n-1)$$
Using this to induct on $n$, we find
$$g_k(n) = \begin{cases}n! & \text{ if } n \leq k \\ k^{n-k}k! & \text { if } n \geq k\end{cases}$$

Then we finish by noting $$f_k(n) = g_{k+1}(n) - g_k(n) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } n \leq k \\ k!\left((k+1)^{n-k} - k^{n-k}\right) & \text{ if } n > k\end{cases}$$